# how to avoid repeating return false line

Tags: javascript

On many functions I have this line:

```
if (!$('.postitle').hasClass('pmarked')) {return false;}
```

To avoid repeating it so often I tried this:

```
function falsea(){
    if (!$('.postitle').hasClass('pmarked')) {return false;}
}
```

and then call the above - `falsea()` instead of  `if (!$('.postitle')...`

It doesn't work.

Is there any simillar way to avoid repeating entire line each time ?

Comment: Can you post more of your code, such as where that line is in the functions you mention?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, this is allways the first line of each function

Comment: *"It doesn't work."* It doesn't work because that's not how function's work. A `return` statement in the callee doesn't cause the caller to terminate.

Comment: That doesn't work because the function flasea returns or false or undefined and undefined evaluates to false.

Comment: @FelixKling, I see, but I tried. So how to terminate the caller?

Comment: You need a `return` statement in the caller. There is nothing around that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The level is incorrect.

`return false` actually do nothing but stop your function for further running.

If you are not outputing any result, this is just same as simply write `return`.

So in your `falsea()` function, your return false stop the function, not the outer one but the `falsea()` itself, it won't make the mother do anything.

What you can do is

```
function falsea(){
    return $('.postitle').hasClass('pmarked'))
}
```

In mother,

```
if (!falsea()) return
```

Answer (score 4):

> It doesn't work.

It doesn't work because that's not how functions work (in any language, really). A `return` statement in the callee doesn't cause the caller to terminate. Simple example:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log('before bar()');
  bar();
  console.log('after bar()');
}

function bar() {
  console.log('in bar; before return');
  return false;
  console.log('in bar; after return');
}

foo();
```

---

What you can do is put the condition in its own function to reuse that, but you still need an `if` statement in every caller:

```
function hasPmarked(){
  return $('.postitle').hasClass('pmarked');
}

// in caller

if (!hasPmarked()) {
  return false;
}
```

> Is there any simillar way to avoid repeating entire line each time ?

You could create a function that accepts a callback and only executes the callback if the check succeeds.

For example:

```
function doStuffIfPMarked(stuff) {
  if ($('.postitle').hasClass('pmarked')) {
    stuff();
  }
}
```

Then the caller can do:

```
doStuffIfPMarked(function() {
  // do something
});
```

I.e. if you had this before:

```
function foo() {
  if (!$('.postitle').hasClass('pmarked')) {return false;}
  // do my stuff
}
```

you would write

```
function foo() {
  doStuffIfPMarked(function() {
    // do my stuff
  });
}
```

You still need to repeat some code, but you are abstracting the condition logic away.

Comment: I would suggest that in the caller the check is the other way round:
function doStuff() { if(hasPmarked() { /* do my stuff */})}

Comment: Yeah, probably better, but we don't know all the details anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your function will only return false or undefined.
Try adding at the end

```
return true;
```

Or even simpler, just do:

```
return !$('.postitle').hasClass('pmarked')
```

Keep in mind that the return doesn't propogate so you will still need check the return value of this function and return.

```
if (falsea()) {return false;}
```